# Regex don't capture before?

Tags: regex

I have the following lines:

**Caller's Address:** aaaaaaa

aaaaa

**Address:** bbbbbb

bbbbb

I have this expression `/Address: [A-z | 0-9]*[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)+/g` which captures both from Address: line and the next.

How can I make sure that I'll only capture the Address: but not Caller's Address?

Comment: Probably  you want `/^Address:\s*(.+)[\r\n]+(.+)/gm`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your regex flavor supports it, you can use a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

`/(<!Caller's )Address: [A-z | 0-9]*[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)+/g`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the negative lookbehind tips. I've actually succeeded with

```
(?<!Caller's )Address: [A-z | 0-9]*[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)+
```